# Difference between db_owner and having all other database roles except the 2 containing the deny keyword

Tags: sql-server, permissions

What is the difference between having only the db_owner database role and having all other except db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter?

db_securityadmin +
db_accessadmin +
db_backupoperator +
db_ddladmin  +
db_datareader +
db_datawriter

Versus

db_owner

I've read that when you have db_accessadmin and db_securityadmin roles, you can change database role of another user into the database but I tried and it seems that I don't have the permission to change any permission while logged with this user. But if I give to this user the db_owner role, now I can change permission to any other user.

Comment: Both of your cases above have db_owner, though. `db_owner > db_securityadmin`. db_securityadmin can *modify role membership for **custom roles** only*.

Comment: Hummm, sorry I really missed while creating a use case and taking screenshots; the first picture should not have the db_owner checked. I will modify my screenshot as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017#fixed-database-roles) article, db_owner can perform functions that no other role or combination of roles provides, including but not limited to:

- Adding users to fixed-database roles
- Dropping the database
- The `CONTROL DATABASE` permission

There is a diagram on the linked article (repeated below) that shows the fixed-role permissions for each role. Any permission not listed in that diagram is granted to the `db_owner` role only by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017#fixed-database-roles) will show you exactly what the differences are.